# could not convert string to float: '12-31'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I need to plot 2 lines with minimum and maximum temperature per day

My dataframe looks like this:

```
 Date  min  max  min2015  max2015
0    01-01 -160  156     -133       11
1    01-02 -267  139     -122       39
2    01-03 -267  133      -67       39
3    01-04 -261  106      -88       44
```

The date column I formatted with day and month only, not year, the reason is that its the MIX and MIX of temperatures between 2004-2014, thats why the year is not present.

so I tried to plot like this:

```
 fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 6))
    axb = ax.twinx()

    # Same as above
    ax.set_xlabel('Date')
    ax.set_ylabel('Temp')
    ax.set_title('Min and Max temperature 2004-2014')
    ax.grid(True)

    # Plotting on the first y-axis
    ax.plot(new_df.Date, new_df['min'], color='tab:orange', label='Min')
    ax.plot(new_df.Date, new_df['max'], color='tab:olive', label='Max')
```

But I get this:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '12-31'
```

Comment: Pandas 1.2.4, Matplotlib 3.3.4 - cannot replicate the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the 'plot' function can not identity string type, you can use 'plot_date' function instead.

```
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('Temp')
plt.title('Min and Max temperature 2004-2014')
plt.grid(True)

plt.plot_date(['01-01', '01-02', '01-03'], [13, 15, 12], color='tab:orange', label='Min')
plt.show()
```

then you can get a picture like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlI1L.png)

Comment: thank you, if I replace plot with plot_date, then I get this: error: 'str' object has no attribute 'toordinal'

Comment: perhaps you can try to update your matplotlib version.

Comment: working on it: pip install --upgrade matplotlib